# How to use options in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

How do I pass values for options in the command line?

I understand that I can pass options or arguments into the command line so that ping behaves differently.  I am specifically wanting to edit the timeout and number of responses requested.

https://www.paessler.com/it-explained/ping tells me I can use -n and -w for this, but I have no experience using command line.

I have tried

```
ping -n=3 SERVERNAME
ping -n ==3 SERVERNAME
ping SERVERNAME -n=3
ping SERVERNAME =n ==3
ping n=3 SERVERNAME
```

and nothing works

I know this may seem like something that has probably been answered here somewhere, but searches on stack exchange for how to use command line options did not help,I generally didnt find anything useful for how to pass variables to options, especially multiple variables, when searching for "command line options," "using command line variables," and "how to use command line variables" on stack overflow or on google (although that may be because google tailors results so most of my results are about how to use command line in python because all of my work computer history is about python)

Please correct my answer if possible.  I just figured stuff out after some time without posting, but I believe the knowledge of such an important task is not easily found right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use an equals sign or comparison operators

for example, to ping but only wait for two responses, the correct syntax (on windows) is

```
ping -n 2 SERVERNAME
```

If you want to use additional options, add them in between the command and the target

for example
`ping -n 2 -w 500 SERVERNAME` will ping twice with a timeout of 500 milliseconds